# PHP MySQL- 1 query counting and displaying records besad on on different "status"

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have table with records that have different "status". So far i use seperate queries to call number of these records depending on the "status". I think (hope) there is a better way (faster) to do so. Any ideas?

My SQL:

```
$res1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT status FROM test WHERE status='1'") 
$num_1 = mysqli_num_rows($res1);

$res2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT status FROM test WHERE status='2'") 
$num_2 = mysqli_num_rows($res2);

$res3 = $mysqli->query("SELECT status FROM test WHERE status='3'") 
$num_3 = mysqli_num_rows($res3);
```

MY PHP

```
echo $num_1;
echo $num_2;
echo $num_3;
```

Comment: never select the rows to count them. ask a database to count and give you the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to get the count of each `status` you can do it like this in one query by using the `group by` clause.

```
select `status`,count(`status`) as 'count' from `test` group by `status`;
```

This would return a recordset like this:

```
+--------+-------+
| status | count |
+--------+-------+
|      1 |    10 |
|      2 |     8 |
|      3 |    12 |
|      4 |     8 |
|      5 |     7 |
|      6 |     3 |
|      7 |     9 |
+--------+-------+
```

So in PHP after you have run the query you could do something like:

```
while( $rs=$result->fetch_object() ) echo $rs->status.'='.$rs->count;



$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'xxx'; 
$dbpwd  = 'xxx'; 
$dbname = 'xxx';
$db  =  new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

$sql="select `status`, count(`status`) as 'count' from `test` group by `status`;";
$result=$db->query( $sql );

while( $rs=$result->fetch_object() ) {
    echo '<div>Status: ' . $rs->status.', Total: ' . $rs->count . '</div>';
}

$db->close();
$db=null;
```

Comment: but how do is display counts separately based on your query?

Comment: statuses are set in db

Comment: Not sure I understand then because the above counts the number of records in the table of each particular status - in the example table there are 10 entries where the status is 1, 8 where the status is 2 and so on...

Comment: I’m sorry I misunderstood you, my question is how do I echo results as shown on the table

Comment: @nita that's a different question. This answer is correct for your current question